# How to match test/control in R

Tags: r, matching, causality, propensity-score-matching

I am new to matching test/control. I saw that in R, we could use either *Matching* or *MatchIt* to select matches. What are differences between the two ways to create matches? Could you provide examples for each of them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of differences between `MatchIt` and `Matching` for performing matching to reduce confounding in observational studies. The most important is the philosophy underlying each package: `MatchIt` considers matching to be a form of nonparametric preprocessing as described in [Ho et al. (2007)](https://doi.org/10.1093/pan/mpl013), while `Matching` consider matching to be a specific estimator of a difference in means, as described in [Abadie and Imbens (2006)](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1468-0262.2006.00655.x). This distinction manifests in that `Matching` provides effect estimates after matching, whereas `MatchIt` only provides a matched dataset that can be supplied to a model to estimate the treatment effect.

There are many other differences between the two packages. `MatchIt` provides an interface to a large variety of matching methods, including nearest neighbor matching, optimal pair matching, optimal full matching, (coarsened) exact matching, genetic matching, propensity score subclassification, and cardinality matching, some of which rely on other packages (including `Matching`!). `Matching` only performs nearest neighbor matching and genetic matching.

The implementation of genetic matching in both packages is about the same because `MatchIt` calls functions in `Matching` to perform the genetic matching. By default, `MatchIt` performs genetic matching on the covariates and propensity score, whereas, in `Matching`, the propensity score must be manually estimated and added along with the covariates. There are some other slight differences that are generally not too relevant.

The implementation of nearest neighbor matching is where the two packages differ the most, though in most cases it is possible to replicate the results of one with the other. The key differences are in the defaults; most capabilities are the same between the two packages. One difference is that `Matching` can perform nearest neighbor matching with ties, whereas `MatchIt` does not allow ties. With numerous continuous covariates, ties rarely occur anyway. Below are some of the differences between the packages:

- The default in `MatchIt` is nearest neighbor matching without replacement on the propensity score; the default in `Matching` is nearest neighbor matching with replacement and ties on the scaled Euclidean distance
- In `Matching`, the matches occur in the order of the data; in `MatchIt`, the user can select the matching order (the default is in descending order of the propensity score)
- In `Matching`, the ATE can be chosen as the estimand when matching with replacement; in `MatchIt`, only the ATT and ATC are available
- `Matching` uses very fast C code to perform the matching; `MatchIt` uses less optimized `Rcpp` code
- `Matching` allows you to customize the matrix used to weight the importance of each covariate in the matching; `MatchIt` allows you to supply a custom distance matrix itself

There are a few other minor differences in options, but the other biggest differences come in the interface. I find `MatchIt` significantly easier to use, especially for beginners, because the interface is similar to that of other R functions like `lm()`, whereas `Matching` requires a bit more manual programming and knowledge of R to use all options effectively. The documentation of `MatchIt` is also significantly more detailed and extensive (note that I wrote it), which can make it easier for beginners. `MatchIt` also provides more tools for visualizing balance.

Which should you use? I say `MatchIt` if you are a beginner or want many options, and `Matching` if you are an econometrician who wants to use the specific estimator `Matching` implements. The interface of `MatchIt` and the ability to use a whole suite of matching methods, along with its extensive documentation aimed at beginners, make `MatchIt` a better choice for those just getting started in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is very clear to me how different Matching and MatchIt are from each other and when I can use which now. Also thanks for writing the documentation for MatchIt!